# What is a finitely connected domain?

Tags: reference-request, definitions

(Cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414738/what-is-a-fintelty-connected-domain).)

The paper *Chang, S.-Y. A. and Yang, P. C.: Conformal deformation of metrics on S 2 . J. Differential Geom., 27(2), 1988* ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214441783), [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=925123)) states in Proposition 2.3 that Moser's inequality holds for

> a piecewise $C^2$, bounded, finitely connected domain in the plane with
> finite number of vertices.

(**Edit:** I replaced “piecewise“ by “piecewise $C^2$”.)

Unfortunately, the term “finitely connected“ is not defined in the paper and Google is of little help to me.

I also asked this question to a colleague who remembered running into the same issue and, being better at using Google than I am, finding *multiple* definitions which (at least on first sight) disagreed. In their case this was not too worrisome as they were studying convex domains which fulfill all these conditions. However, I would be interested what precisely is needed for the cited proposition.

Thus, I am asking for reference introducing this term and perhaps also for a discussion of different definitions. (Perhaps they all agree?)

**Edit:** Let me make my question more precise and ask whether the definitions given in the comments coincide: Is

- fundamental group finitely generated

equivalent to

- Betti number $p^1$ finite

(for piecewise $C^2$, bounded connected domains in the plane with finite number of vertices)?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would assume “finitely connected” means the fundamental group is finite, or finitely presented, or finitely generated. (cf “simply connected” and “multiply connected”)

Comment: If you give a list of competing definitions, the question would be easier to answer. I would guess that by a finitely-connected domain the authors mean a compact embedded surface in the plane whose boundary circles are polygonal curves. In other words, consider a plane disk $D$ with polygonal boundary and remove from the interior of $D$ the interiors of finitely many disjoint disks with polygonal boundaries. On the other hand, maybe they also permit removing finitely many points from the interior of $D$.

Comment: From the title of the book I infer that they are talking about a domain on a surface. For this case, "finitely connected" has the standard meaning that the fundamental group is finitely generated.

Comment: See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Multiply-connected_domain

Comment: The question is actually not what "finitely-connected" means. It is what "piecewise, bounded, finitely connected domain in the plane with finite number of vertices" means.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko At this point, they are talking about a domain on a plane, that is, a very simple surface.

Comment: @lhf and AlexandreEremenko: Thanks. Is “fundamental group is finitely generated“ equivalent to “Betti number $p^1$ finite“?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I am not sure whether I understand your definition, but I guess this would not include any smooth domain? That would seem very odd to me.

Comment: @Keba I have no access to the paper so until you replaced "piecewise" by "piecewise C^2$" I assumed the boundary is polygonal. I am still not sure whether your definition includes say punctured disk.

Comment: @Keba: for a finitely connected domain in the plane, the fundamental group is free, and the first homology group is is just the product of finitely many Z's. Both have n generators, and this n is the connectivity of the domain.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thanks, so the two definitions coincide, yes? And roughly speaking the domain may have finitely many “holes“, yes? Is the punctured disc admissible in the referenced proposition?

Comment: @Keba: yes. A finitely connected domain in the plane is one whose complement has finitely many components (holes). Yes, punctures are counted too as holes. For each hole there is one generator of the fundamental group, and loops around the holes make a basis of homology.